# What will be the css selector for jquery nextAll()

Tags: jquery, css

**Jquery**

```
var obj = $('.grp[data-id=r7c1]').parent().nextAll("td").andSelf().slice(0, 3);
obj.find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true).toggleClass('grp done');
```

What will be the CSS selector for above code?

Ex: CSS

```
input[type=checkbox][data-id=r7c1][disabled] + label:before{
    content:'done';
}
```

please, could anyone help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: `nextAll('td')` would be `~ td`, but if you're trying to step up to the parent from `.grp`, you can't.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn is there any other way?

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: @Dom http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/2JMgZ/19/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/2JMgZ/24/ ?

Comment: @Andrew i want to use slice(0, 3) also

Answer (score 0):

Try this type.

```
$(this).nextAll('td')
```

Comment: `this` is dependent on scope.  The OP is not using a function, so `this` would either refer to the `window` or, more likely, the `document` if it is being declared within a `document.ready()` (`$(function(){}`).